# Using Angular 8 Injectable service inside Web Worker

Tags: angular, typescript, service, web-worker, injectable

I have an Angular application which initialises Web Worker and starts some rendering operations inside it. Worker has instance of helper class Renderer to perform rendering operations.

Now I need to get real time data from RealtimeDataService (@Injectable) to feed to the Renderer.

But when I'm importing the service inside my helper class Renderer (or directly to the worker typescript file), compiler is throwing me this error:

ERROR in ./src/app/workers/ecg.worker.ts (./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js!./src/app/workers/ecg.worker.ts)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js):
Error: ../../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(1470,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(9115,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(10194,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(13467,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(13481,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'.

How can I use injectable service inside Web Worker context?

Comment: Hi, did you solve it?